# can not send text message with balebot npm

Tags: node.js, websocket, bots, bale-messenger

I've downloaded balebot npm and used this code for sending 200 text messages to a clients with it (either could be used for a banch of clients).
any ideas?

```
const SDK = require("balebot");
const BaleBot = SDK.BaleBot;
const FileMessage = SDK.FileMessage;
const TextMessage = SDK.TextMessage;

let bot = new BaleBot('My token');

var file = new TextMessage("its a text message")

for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    bot.send(file, new SDK.User(201707397, "-9120776543768627721")).then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
}
```

but i'm puzzled with this error.

```
BotErrorResponse {
  _id: '1001',
  _body: { code: 403, tag: 'HIT_LIMIT', data: {}, retryIn: null },
  code: 403,
  tag: 'HIT_LIMIT',
  data: {},
  retryIn: null }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is talking about the limitaion of sending messages to a client(s) with bots. you should use a method to send them with delay. 
learn more : https://developers.bale.ai/

Comment: A great introduction about Bale application!